# Derivation of conserved current

Tags: conservation-laws, field-theory, integration, calculus

Can someone give me some steps on showing the last line.

[image]

From the line, $$-\int d^3x \space \epsilon_{abc} \space [ (\nabla^2\phi_b) \phi_c - m^2\phi_b\phi_c ] $$ I cannot actually see how could this end up with the expression,
$$ \int d^3x \space \epsilon_{abc} \space \nabla\phi_b \cdot \nabla\phi_c .$$

One idea that I am considering is by using this properties of divergence,

$$ \nabla \cdot (\phi_c \nabla \phi_b) = \nabla\phi_c \cdot \nabla \phi_b + \phi_c (\nabla \cdot \nabla\phi_b) $$

but one would end up with an additional term,

$$ \int d^3x \space \epsilon_{abc} \space (\nabla \cdot \phi_c\nabla \phi_b) = \oint_S \epsilon_{abc} \space \phi_c\nabla \phi_b  \cdot dS \hat{n} .$$

I do not know how to prove that this integral is zero, can someone show me some steps or maybe some insights in going into the right track?

Comment: Assuming $\phi_a = 0$ on the boundary, your last integral becomes identically equal to zero (since you're integrating 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exactly right in your thinking, you must consider the total derivative (i.e. $\nabla\cdot f$), expand it, and then apply the divergence theorem to the total derivative term (only)  to get a surface integral at infinity. This is extremely common in QFT. The integral $$\oint_S \epsilon_{abc} \space \phi_c\nabla \phi_b  \cdot dS \hat{n} $$ goes to $0$ because we assume $\phi = \nabla\phi = 0$  at infinity for all scalar quantum fields so for that entire integration domain, $\phi_c=\nabla\phi_b = 0$ so its identically $0$.

The reason for the cavalier boundary conditions on the fields and their derivatives at infinity has to do with a wavepacket treatment of the fields (that is needed but not often explicitely written in textbooks). This is not justified in textbooks like Srednicki for instance **but is needed** to see this boundary conditions.